# In the A* (path finding) algorithm, why must h() be *admissible*?

Tags: algorithm

According to [the Wikipedia article on the A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) it says:

> Here, g(n) is the known cost of getting from the initial node to n;
>   this value is tracked by the algorithm. h(n) is a heuristic estimate
>   of the cost to get from n to any goal node. For the algorithm to find
>   the actual shortest path, the heuristic function must be admissible,
>   meaning that it never overestimates the actual cost to get to the
>   nearest goal node. The heuristic function is problem-specific and must
>   be provided by the user of the algorithm.

It specifically states that the *h()* function must not *overestimate* the distance. Yet, it seems to me that in my code if my heuristic *h()* function returns infinity (or zero) it performs just as well and still finds the shortest path.

So why should it be *admissable*? Isn't a value of infinity overestimating my heuristic? I feel like my node graph is complex enough. Are there specific situations where this would make a difference that I perhaps have not reproduced in my graph?

**Addendum:**
See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kh8pyhg7/10/) and feel free to mess with the h function at line 221. Click on the floorplan to move the red dot.

Any of the following commented lines work equally well for the h() function.

```
var h = function(a,b) {
    //return calcDistance(a,b);
    //return 0;
    return 999999;
}
```

Comment: When I set the length to return 0, then when going around the outside of the house, the dot sometimes doesn't take the shortest path.

Comment: @Mooing Duck. Really? Which path? I'm not seeing see that. Does the path change when you change h()?

Comment: 0 is admissible, that just turns A* into Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: @harold, so then what is the *h()* providing to the A* algorithm that Djikstra's algorithm can't account for?

Comment: Efficiency. The point of an informed search is that it doesn't need as much searching (well it might, but not typically), it can identify "bad directions" and avoid searching that way (it still may, but only if necessary). Dijkstra on an empty map explores a circle until the edges hits the target. A* on an empty map explores only the shortest path and its immediate vicinity.

Answer (score 1):

If your heuristic is not admissible, then you will sometimes "settle for less than the best."

Suppose your search has just reached the goal node. Can you stop? Or is there yet to be found a better path to the goal?

If the heuristic always *underestimates* the shortest path from any node to the goal, you can look at each frontier node N and compare (Cost to get to N) + (Heuristic for N) to (Cost to get to the goal via the path I already found). If there isn't any node N for which it is still possible to find a shorter path to the goal, then you're done.

If your heuristic is not admissible, this reasoning will not work.

Comment: You should also explain why he's not seeing any issues with his jsfiddle.

Comment: Once you arrive at your goal node then *h* is irrelevant since the full length will have been calculated and will fall under the *g*.

Comment: @Octopus That isn't true. When you first arrive at the goal node, it just means you have found *some* path to the goal. But you don't know it's the best path.

Comment: I didn't say you knew it was best, but you do know its actual length which is g. And if you are comparing g, why do you need h?

Comment: @Octopus You are not comparing g; you are comparing f = g + h.  h at the goal is 0.  This is why in my answer I said "compare (Cost to get to N) + (Heuristic for N) to (Cost to get to the goal via the path I already found)."

Comment: @Timothy, h = heuristic of distance between current node and the goal. What is h when the current node is the goal? There is no remaining distance, hence h=0 and f=g. !!! Thus when you compare two complete paths it is g vs g the h's are both 0.

Comment: @Octopus You are not comparing the goal node with itself; you are comparing the goal node with every other node in the frontier. Those nodes have h > 0 usually.

Comment: So are you saying that as long as h is *admissible* then the first path that the algorithm dumps out *will* be the shortest? And if its not *admissible* then we can't be guaranteed that it is the shortest.

Comment: @Octopus no, when the frontier node with minimal f = g + h score is the goal node, the path to it is the shortest.  This comment section is getting too long I think...